# Forcing the www prefix with PHP/htaccess/mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there an easy way (preferably with htaccess and mod_rewrite) to force the browser to always access a site with the www. prefix (adding it automatically where necessary?)

Thx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

or maybe

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to work, as the site sits in a subdomain on the server.  Is there a way to make it global?

Comment: @DCD, see update. If that isn't what you mean perhaps you can update your question with some more information?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]` (without that first slash)? At least for me the RewriteRules do not include that initial slash.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I use:

```
$url= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$page=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
if($url == "example.com"){
    header("Location: http://www.example.com$page");
}
```

Comment: This is great because it completely avoids the need to use .htaccess (which can be unnecessarily fiddly/prone to being incompatible). This works on all platforms. Great!

Comment: Neat! This idea can be extended to create permalinks.

Comment: You could put $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] for example.com so that this works without being edited every time. substr "www" on the comparison.