# 301 redirect from www.domain.com/index.html to www.domain.com not working

Tags: redirect, joomla, httpd.conf

In apache configuration file (i.e., httpd.conf) we had virtual host configuration, which is working for last 2 years. Today to there no problem with it. But when I was asked to add redirection to it, it's not working. My virtualHost conatainer looks something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName domain.com
  Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/
  Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here when I'm typing "http://domain.com" it is taking to "http://www.domain.com" expected behaviour. But when I type "http://domain.com/index.html" or "http://www.domain.com/index.html" it is not taking me to "http://www.domain.com"...it is joomla website.

Can anyone resolve this for me...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

in a new row after `ServerName domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's applying the first redirect before trying the second one.
Have you tried putting the Redirect lines in the other order?

```
  Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.domain.com/
  Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Usualy this is achieved by using a more general approach with mod_rewrite :

This code should be placed in the htaccess file in the root of your domain, i.e. domain.com/.htaccess
or the virtualhost configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

( e.g. also here [Forcing the www prefix with PHP/htaccess/mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527788/forcing-the-www-prefix-with-php-htaccess-mod-rewrite) )